# Recoding an operator such as "&" to text in a string in R

Tags: r

I have a column in R with text however I want to recode `&` to "and".

I have tried using the `recode` function

```
data$Value <- recode(data$Value, "& = and")
```

I get an error message that says:

> Error in recode(data$Value, "& = and") : in recode term: & = and
>   message: Error in parse(text = strsplit(term, "=")[[1]][1]) : 
>   :1:1: unexpected '&'1: & ^

Comment: better if you made a reproducible example

Comment: I'd consider this a typo: `recode` expects a (possibly named) vector, such as in the docs example `recode(num_vec, \`2\` = 20L, \`4\` = 40L)`. I can't think of any situations where such arguments would be given with a string that includes `=`; generally these would be `x = "blah"` or for named vectors could be `"x" = "blah"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And option is `sub`

```
sub("&", "and", data$Value, fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close. You can't quote everything. Try this

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c("&", "a", "b", "c")
recode(a, "&" = "and")
[1] "and" "a"   "b"   "c"
```